# MergeSort Issues: "... VariableDeclaratorId" to complete FormalParameterList

Tags: java, arraylist, mergesort

I am working on mergeSort with comparable arraylists. I have theses errors come up:
- Syntax error, insert "... VariableDeclaratorId" to complete 
     FormalParameterList
    - Method breakpoint:Sorts [entry] - mergesort()
Here is my code, what do I do?

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
public class Sorts 
{
public ArrayList<Comparable> yay = new ArrayList<Comparable>();
public ArrayList<Comparable> helper = new ArrayList<Comparable>();

public Sorts() 
{

}

private void mergesort(List<Comparable> yay, int low, int high)
{
 if (low < high) 
{
  int middle = low + (high - low) / 2;
  mergesort(yay, low, middle);
  mergesort( yay, middle + 1, high);
  merge(low, middle, high);
}
}

private void merge(int low, int middle, int high) 
{
for (int i = low; i <= high; i++) 
{
  helper.set(i,yay.get(i)) ;
}

int i = low;
int j = middle + 1;
int k = low;
while (i <= middle && j <= high) 
{
  if (helper.get(i).compareTo( helper.get(j))<=0) 
  {
    yay.set(k, helper.get(i));
    i++;
  } 
  else 
  {
    yay.set(k, helper.get(j));
    j++;
  }
  k++;
}

while (i <= middle) 
{
  yay.set(k, helper.get(i));
  k++;
  i++;
}
}

public static void main(String[] args) 
{
ArrayList<Comparable> bla = new ArrayList<Comparable>();
bla.add(2);
bla.add(4);
bla.add(3);
bla.add(1);
  Sorts test = new Sorts();
  System.out.println(bla);
  test.mergesort(bla, 0, 0);
  System.out.println("Sorted:");
  for(int i=0; i< bla.size();i++)
  {
      System.out.println(bla.get(i));
  }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`private void mergesort(List<Comparable>)`, you specified the parameter type, but did not give it a name,  like:

```
private void mergesort(List<Comparable> list)
```

Comment: BTW, low and high are not initialized.  based on the recursive calls, seems like they should be parameters

Comment: So I would put yay as my "name"?

Comment: How do I initialize them or make them parameters?

Comment: Where it look like this: private void mergesort(List<Comparable> yay)

Comment: you could do that, but that will hide the class-level definition.  If this is the list you want to sort, then just access it directly, and change mergesort declaration to:  `mergesort(int low, int high)`

Comment: I want to hide it. But I then get this when I call 
mergesort(yay,low, middle);  
mergesort(yay, middle + 1, high);
The method mergesort(List<Comparable>) in the type Sorts is not applicable for the arguments (List<Comparable>, int, int)

Comment: then mergesort should be defined as:  `private void mergesort(List<Comparable> yay, int low, int high)`

Comment: when i do that and run the program it does not sort

Comment: I'm assuming you did not change merge to also take yay as a parameter, so it's operation on the class instance, not the one passed to mergesort.  Can you update the source above with what you have now (and please format it better)?

Comment: sure let me do that now